# fetching from openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

trying to fetch data from OpenWeatherMap API then trying to display it in the console but the response is HTML page that contains no data and response status is 200...it should be JSON I tried the API in postman and it worked and displayed the correct data but here it keeps throwing an error of Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
I tried different scenarios of fetching using different methods it all failed to fix

```
const Fetching = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&q=London&appid=31c3627d9d33b84c7a575fc11b6d7dfe');
  const responsedata= await response.json();
  console.log(responsedata);
};
  Fetching();
```

Comment: Unexpected token < at position 0 usually means you're parsing HTML as if it was JSON. Did you look at the actual content of the response?

Answer (score 0):

please fix your url like below

```
 const Fetching = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&q=London&appid=31c3627d9d33b84c7a575fc11b6d7dfe');
        const responsedata = await response.json();
        console.log(responsedata);
    };

Fetching();
```